# bond energy calories

Tags: bond, energy, free-energy

I am attempting to optimize interactions for a series of random and test molecules to a protein using docking software. The software uses QM/MMGBSA to calculate free energy in joules (yes it is not a measurement but it is very corollary). Larger molecules automatically have more free energy because they have greater potential energy. I would like to divide the free energy by the amount of atoms in the molecule or the molecules total Dalton. The idea would be to normalize the energy and provide the amount of calories associated with the bond. I asked a professor at a university about measuring the efficiency of a bond in this manner and he said he was unsure what joule/mass would provide. It does appear that the amount of bond calories is able to properly classify with correct magnitudes of viability 2 positive controls and 1 negative but I need this idea to pass peer review. Is my rationalization of the joule/Dalton reasonable?

I am measuring the binding energy of azttp (AZT triphosphate), gtp (Guanine triphosphate) and AZTppppA (AZTP+AMP) on HIV Reverse Transcriptase wild type (8ICO). I am used 8 high quality conformers and independent docks with QM/MMGBSA for my negative sample (AZT+AMP), 5 conformers for my major positive sample (AZTTP) and 1 conformer for the minor positive sample (gtp). I have two or three high quality conformers through the same processes for each of my test samples.

HIV RT has a tunnel where nucleotide analogs pass through with a pocket where if a molecule binds effectively it is accepted but if it fails it is phosphorylated and excreted. I am attempting to create a metric which can be used to measure the effectiveness of a binding and allowing me to infer (only) probability of rejection. Since the window/box for the docking is small and does not change for each test subject I would like to consider HIV-RT a constant.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about what you are measuring and what you are trying to measure? Typically docking calculations yield the CHANGE in free energy between the bound and unbound state of a ligand-protein complex. 

As you pointed out this can be different for larger/smaller molecules but is more highly influenced by the types of groups interacting, conformation of the ligand in the pocket etc.

Comment: @CTKlein i updated the question with more information as per your request

Comment: >Is my rationalization of the joule/Dalton reasonable? || No. Standard scheme for measuring bond energies is to calculate free energies for complex and subtract energies of two separate molecules. In your case you probably have to calculate free energies for biological conditions and then derive constant of reaction. After that you have to solve classical problem of amount of bound/unbound molecules using some known (medically meaningful) starting concentrations

Comment: @permeakra thank you for your response but larger molecules have a greater probability of forming larger complexes as CTKlein points out

Comment: @caseyr547 first, masses are irrelevant in the case then =) for obvious reason. Second, chelate effect does exist. And third, I don't think 'mass' or 'size' has any meaning. AFAIK, in medicine new substance has to be 1) efficient ligand 2) specific ligand 3) not unreasonably costly per use case. 4)not extremely toxic. Joule/Dalton does not address any of this issues.

Comment: @permeakra I'm sure your great with chemistry but as CTKlein pointed out and i observe mass effects the efficiency to some measurable degree. While I'm sure your comments about the constant of reaction rate would work well in non static situations that is not the case here. Also calculating the free energy in a biological condition is impossible given our current technological advancement.

Comment: That's not really the point I was making. I was pointing out that molecules of different size will have to adjust accordingly in a binding pocket and/or the binding pocket may change its conformation. Inherently, this has nothing to do with the mass of the ligand.

Also I'm still not clear what exactly you are measuring when you say "free energy". As mentioned, a docking calculation will give you a the CHANGE in free energy. In your case that would be G(complex)-G(ligand)-G(protein). This value is a metric for how tightly the ligand binds which may or may not be what you're interested in.

Comment: @CTKlein The formula for deta G which I am using is dG = E_complex-minimized- (E_ligand_minimized + E_receptor_minimized). My hypothesis which I observe to be correct in 3 cases is: The probability of forming more complexes and generating a lower dG is higher when there are more atoms to form complexes in the ligand molecule.

Comment: @caseyr547 Once more. ligands with several points of binding binds more efficiently if the centers can assume fitting positions. It is not an artificial effect and is quite well-known in coordination chemistry. If you want metric measuring effectiveness of binding it is exactly free energy of binding. There is completely different matter, that you have to compare it with binding energy of water at same sites and to measure actual preference, but that's different matter. So you probably have either to live with what you have or reformulate the question

Comment: @permeakra summed it up nicely. If the pocket is big enough to accommodate the larger ligands you are testing then they are likely binding in more locations than the smaller ligands, hence lower free energy of binding. There is a multitude of interactions that need to be considered when measuring binding free energies (water in the pocket, types of chemical groups on the ligands/pocket etc.). While it would be wonderful if a metric as simple as mass were a good indicator for binding energy, it simply isn't the case.

Comment: @CTKlein ok the pocket is big enough to accommodate massive ligands and they are binding in more locations. Can I divide the energy by the amount of binding locations?

Comment: @CTKlein the goal would be to average the energy contribution per bond.

Comment: @permeakra yes the energy alone gives the metric of quantity but it does not give the metric of quality of the bond. 6 random bonds with 10 atoms total is less than 6 specific bonds with 10 atoms and is less than 3 specific bonds with 4 atoms total. The energy for the 6 random bonds would be greater than the energy of the 3 specific bonds but on average the quality would not be as good.

Comment: @caseyr547 I see. In this case I'd considered two options. Option one is to dock as many molecules of water simultaneously as I can and then check how many water molecules cover binding site of the ligand in question. Another option is to check the surface of contact between the binding ligand and the host protein. Both metrics are hard to measure, but they have some meaning at the very least. The last option is to divide by number of atomic contacts between the ligand and the protein.]

Comment: @permeakra yes ok dividing the energy by the number of contacts is possible but it has to be done by hand. i have a program which will count the number of contacts for individual ligands. if i did it right, gtp has 178 contacts and aztamp has 400. gtp has a complex dg of -36 and aztamp likewise is -79. From this, Can I safely conclude that aztamp contacts are individually no better than gtp?